# Reading from a single file and writing into 2 seperate files gives unexpected results

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract some values from a Slurm output file using Python but the `write()` method doesn't seem to work as expected (or I'm not understanding the use of it that well).

[Link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=44796760467626715123) to download the output file  `slurm-5089.out`:

Extracting the values only and putting them in two separate files was successful :

```py
for line in f:
    if line[:2] == "nu":
        nuof.write(line[5:])
    if line[:2] == "C ":
        Cof.write(line[4:])
```

But when I try to divide the values (150 for each category/file) into sub-categories (nu-SVC or C-SVC, 30 values for each one) by mention that before every group of values belonging to a specific sub-category it doesn't give the expected results, this is the last piece of code I used to do so:

```py
for line in f:
    if line[:4] == "**Tr":
        if i in nu:
            print(i)
            print(type[i])
            nuof.write(type[i]+'\n')
            print(line)
            i += 1
        if  i in C:
            print(i)
            print(type[i])
            Cof.write(type[i]+'\n')
            print(line)
            i += 1
```

for the files I opened, the lists `nu`, `C`, `type` and the counter `i` that I used, this is their initialization:

```py
from __future__ import print_function

i = 0

nu = [0,1,2,3,4]
C = [5,6,7,8]

type = ['-----nu-SVC-----', '-----nu-SVC-----', '-----nu-SVC-----', '-----nu-SVC-----', '-----nu-SVC-----', '-----C-SVC-----', '-----C-SVC-----', '-----C-SVC-----', '-----C-SVC-----']

Cof = open('C_values', 'w')
nuof = open('nu_values', 'w')
f = open('slurm-5089.out', 'r')
```

This is how I'm adding the first `-----def-----` in my `C_values` file:

```py
Cof.write('-----def-----\n')
```

[Link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=65047510144988833056) to download the output I got in `C_values` file.

[Link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=55267245647389072054) to download the output I got in `nu_values` file.

This is what I'm planning to obtain:

```
-----def-----
1.067648
1.699384
1.137877
2.148189
327.390817
2.668285
1.015005
1.834085
1.085050
2.512783
330.863862
2.492146
1.016106
1.741183
0.905885
2.451512
477.157341
2.679206
1.118905
1.952953
1.071948
2.459619
400.765942
2.798353
0.783165
1.990212
0.877010
2.093311
331.349704
2.671817
-----C-SVC-----
0.121222
0.196481
0.126245
0.350959
9036.687632
0.459966
0.111442
0.213469
0.128784
0.430376
8188.026398
0.436184
0.118351
0.201235
0.108417
0.400938
10286.065268
0.433921
0.129255
0.226374
0.126481
0.482451
13273.184496
0.525713
0.097013
0.236698
0.105254
0.344640
6230.513754
0.458801
-----C-SVC-----
16.107007
21.039873
16.553491
30.173238
1674.267295
35.782899
15.238036
20.423749
16.830935
31.339246
1698.550375
31.147013
16.274621
20.223880
16.434865
31.521544
2353.794493
36.805332
16.764180
23.052520
17.781023
31.867347
2182.786987
32.875505
13.401091
23.094557
14.890684
25.336002
1653.916156
34.239836
-----C-SVC-----
1.067648
1.699384
1.137877
2.148189
327.390817
2.668285
1.015005
1.834085
1.085050
2.512783
330.863862
2.492146
1.016106
1.741183
0.905885
2.451512
477.157341
2.679206
1.118905
1.952953
1.071948
2.459619
400.765942
2.798353
0.783165
1.990212
0.877010
2.093311
331.349704
2.671817
-----C-SVC-----
2.319126
3.974477
2.463397
7.358145
130.813731
9.923179
2.175899
4.486890
2.503507
9.056446
129.852183
9.817307
2.256106
4.008876
2.078878
8.397495
113.754769
9.262230
2.685915
4.782272
2.459403
11.044663
120.761463
10.852858
1.885747
4.804282
1.992187
8.006820
118.607456
10.239223
```

Some parts in the `C_values` file are actually well organized, the values are splited into the exact expected number (30 values for each sub-category) which are the last 2 group of values, and from `-----def-----` until the first `-----C-SVC-----` there are exactly 90 values which represent 3 sub-categories; in this example (for `C_values` only) the values should be splited into 5 parts, which is how many separators [titles] are in the file, which proves that the counting is actually performing well, but I don't quite understand how the loop acted with the last two `-----C-SVC-----` in the output file, and with the 90 values group, I tried to write different pieces of code but none of them worked and the provided one gave a close result to what I'm wanting to have, would it be something with my built-in `write()` method or I'm missing something here ?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and add an example of the data in input file being read, which I think is `'slurm-5089.out'` from what's in your example code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In addition to what @martineau mentioned, I'm not quite clear on what's wrong with the output you're getting. If you could include the output you're expecting that would help.

Comment: Martineau ,thanks for the suggestion.... @Harry-Cutts Thank you I'm happy to be active in the community I did add what I'm expecting to obtain in the output file I hope the difference is clear to you, thanks again

Comment: @Mo-Ng The reason is probably that your log file does not contain any more lines that match the `"nu"` or `"C "` pattern. However, since the example data you provided seems to be incomplete (it contains only 5 lines starting with `**Tr`) this is hard to tell. You might need to use an external file hosting service to provide the full log file.

Comment: @a_guest Thank you for the remarque; actually, I didn't plan to take the ```nu``` and ```C``` pattern into account in order to write ```-----C-SVC-----``` / ```-----nu-SVC-----``` to my files, it was just banal logic, counting how many ```**Tr``` patters are their (manually) and code it (the code will be used on many other output files); I also included the links to download the ```C_values``` and the ```nu_values``` files

Comment: If `i`is 4, you will run the `nu` block, increment it to 5, and then run the `C` block **too**.

Comment: @DavisHerring It's the same problem with the ```nu_values file``` (if the ```if i in nu:```  was running as you mentioned it will perform as expected to), if you take a look at the ```nu_values``` file you will notice that the output it's not organized as planned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went another path, and it gave the results I wanted, I tried to write the
`nu` values and the `C` values to the `nu_values` and `C_values` files, and at the same time when a counter (variable `i`) reaches a certain number (variable `count`,in this case, it's `30`) the algorithm writes the selected message from the `type[]` list (in my last code I changed that to `tp[]` since `vim` editor highlights it as a python keyword), and then it assigns `0` to `i` in order to start over again, the problem of this even that it gave an extraordinary performance (almost 4 minutes for a file of 245 MB in size), is that it calls a function inside a function and it reads the input file (`sys.argv[1]`) to count the lines which begin with `nu` or `C` first and then after that it starts the writing process (so it is **kind of** repeating the same process), but anyway this is my solution:

```
tp = ['---C1----\n', '----C2----\n', '-----C3-----\n', '-----C4-----\n', '-----N1-----\n', '-----N2-----\n', '-----N3-----\n', '-----N4-----\n']


def line_counter():
    count = 0
    f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
    for line in f.xreadlines():
        if line[:2] == "nu":
            count += 1
        if line[:2] == "C ":
            count += 1
    f.close()
    return count


def to_file():
    Cof = open('C_values_'+sys.argv[1], 'w')
    nuof = open('nu_values_'+sys.argv[1], 'w')
    f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
    Cof.write("-----Cdef-----\n")
    nuof.write("-----Ndef-----\n")
    count = (line_counter()/10)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 4
    for line in f:
        if line[:2] == "C ":
            i += 1
            Cof.write(line[4:])
            if i == count:
                if j in (0,1,2,3):
                    Cof.write(tp[j])
                i = 0
                j += 1
        if line[:2] == "nu":
            i += 1
            nuof.write(line[5:])
            if i == count:
                if k in (4,5,6,7):
                    nuof.write(tp[k])
                i = 0
                k += 1
    f.close()
    nuof.close()
    Cof.close()
    print("Finished!")
```